# Ruby: How to walk thru db record to return true key/value pair

Tags: ruby, activerecord

How can I return the key value pair that is `true` from this database record. Can't seem to get it this morning, probably need more coffee..

Here is my code:

```
def get_enabled_speeds_from_db
  @speed_details = []
  current_speeds.each do |speed|
    @speed_details << shop.speeds.find_by(shipping_speed: speed)
  end
end
```

In the above method `current_speeds` is just an array with the speeds listed, it looks like this:

```
["Standard", "Expedited"]
```

And when the method finishes, `speed_details` looks like this:

```
[#<Speed id: 51, shipping_speed: "Standard", fixed: false, fixed_amount: nil, flex: true, flex_dollar_or_percent: "$", flex_amount: #<BigDecimal:411ebb8,'0.1E2',9(18)>, free: false, free_shipping_amount: nil, created_at: "2018-07-11 18:39:17", updated_at: "2018-07-11 18:39:17", store_id: 15, enabled: true>, #<Speed id: 52, shipping_speed: "Expedited", fixed: true, fixed_amount: #<BigDecimal:3f6e2a0,'0.1E2',9(18)>, flex: false, flex_dollar_or_percent: "", flex_amount: nil, free: true, free_shipping_amount: 25.0, created_at: "2018-07-11 18:39:46", updated_at: "2018-07-11 18:39:46", store_id: 15, enabled: true>]
```

Now what I want to do is step thru `speed_details` to pull out the key/value pairs that are set to `true`. For example, in `speed id:51` `flex: true` and `enabled: true`. And in `speed id: 52` `fixed` is `true`.

This is my method to do this, but I can't use `select` on `speed`. I've tried changing to an array and enum, but I need the key/value pair, not just if true exists.

```
def get_enabled_speed_details_that_are_true
  speed_details.each do |speed|
    speed_name = {speed: speed[:shipping_speed]}
    whats_turned_on = speed.select{|k,v| v == true }
    walk_thru_each_rate_type(speed_name.merge(whats_turned_on))
  end
end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might first want to get only those fields whose values are boolean i.e can be only true/false and then filter from it.

```
final_result = []
Model.select('field1, field2, field3').each do |model|
  current_matching_result = model.attributes.collect{|key,value| key if value ==true}
  if current_matching_result.compact.present?
    truthy_array = [true] * current_matching_result.count
    filtered_attributes_hash = current_matching_result.zip(truthy_array).to_h.merge!({id: model.id})
    final_result << filtered_attributes_hash
  end
end
```